# Working with numbers in a generic way. Parsing and division

Tags: scala

So, `Numeric[T]` type class in scala allows operations `+`, `-`, and `*`. But it does not provide `/` operation and `fromString :: String -> Option[T]`. I have to write:

```
    abstract class NumParser[A] {
      def unapply(s: String): Option[A]
      def /(x: A, y: A): A
    }

    implicit val doubleParser = new NumParser[Double]() {
      import scala.util.Try
      def unapply(s: String): Option[Double] = Try(s.toDouble).toOption
      def /(x: Double, y: Double) = x / y
    }

    ...
```

Each time I need to work with numbers in a generic way.

Both operations are quite common and I wonder whether I'm missing something and they are implemented in scala or some other common library (like scalaz), and I just didn't notice that.

I am aware that scala has `Fractional` and `Integral`, which has `/`. But I can't use them simultaneously.

I'd like `/` op to be `Int -> Int -> Int` for `Int` and `Double -> Double -> Double` for `Double`

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to be able to do two different things, division and quot (integer divsion), depending on the type. Then you would have to invent your own type class. You could simply wrap `Integral` and `Fractional`:

```
// prefer Integral over Fractional
trait LowPriStrangeDiv {
  implicit def fromFractional[A](implicit f: Fractional[A]): StrangeDiv[A] =
    new StrangeDiv[A] {
      def strangeDiv(a: A, b: A): A = f.div(a, b)
    }
}
object StrangeDiv extends LowPriStrangeDiv {
  implicit def fromIntegral[A](implicit i: Integral[A]): StrangeDiv[A] =
    new StrangeDiv[A] {
      def strangeDiv(a: A, b: A): A = i.quot(a, b)
    }
}
trait StrangeDiv[A] {
  def strangeDiv(a: A, b: A): A
}
```

Test:

```
implicit class DivSyntax[A](private val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def / (b: A)(implicit d: StrangeDiv[A]) : A = d.strangeDiv(a, b)
}

def test[A: StrangeDiv](a: A, b: A): A = a / b

assert(test(10  , 4  ) == 2  )
assert(test(10.0, 4.0) == 2.5)
```

Or you forget about `Integral` and `Fractional` and define individual cases:

```
object StrangeDiv {
  implicit object IntDiv extends StrangeDiv[Int] {
    def strangeDiv(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a / b
  }
  implicit object DoubleDiv extends StrangeDiv[Double] {
    def strangeDiv(a: Double, b: Double): Double = a / b
  }
}
trait StrangeDiv[A] {
  def strangeDiv(a: A, b: A): A
}
```

Comment: That's a one way to go, but it still requires writing this code piece over and over. Do you think `/` operation is separated into different `Fractional` and `Integral` by design? My motivation is that in code you write `4 / 2` and `4.0 / 2.0` using the same symbol, so it should be represented in a single type class, although I agree the operation is different

Comment: Also what's with parsing? Is there any help from standard libraries on that?

Comment: P.S. I was converting Haskell example into Scala which I thought was capable of doing things I've posted, but I've just realized that they switched from `Num a` to `Float` type constraint in example, so that's explain things a bit. If Haskell can't do that, then scala can't probably do that as well

Comment: Yes, I think they are separated because it is unclear what the integer equivalent of a fractional division is and what the floating point equivalent of an integer quotient is. The primitive operator `/` is inherited from Java. I am not aware that there is a standard type class for string parsing.

Comment: Also note that [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire#type-classes) makes the same distinction between "number types, where / is true division" and "number types, where / is floor division"

Comment: Actually Spire defines `MultiplicativeGroup` for both `Int` and `Double` and it doesn't make a distinction if you use `Numeric` type class. `def check[A: Numeric](x: A, y: A): A = x / y; check[Int](10, 4); check[Double](10.3, 4.3)` works great. Thank you for pointing me to this great library. Unfortunately it looks like Spire cannot parse `Numeric` from string, at least I haven't found this functionality there yet